# Injection of autowired dependencies failed for abstract class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, abstract-class

I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4

I have the following class structure

```
public interface GenericDAO<T> {

    public void create(T entity);
    public void update(T entity);
    public void delete(T entity);
}
```

**DAO class**

```
public interface EmployeeDAO extends GenericDAO<Employee>  {

    public void findEmployee(EmployeeQueryData data);
}
```

**DAO Implementation class**

```
@Repository("employeeDAO")
public abstract class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
public void findEmployee(EmployeeQueryData data) {

...... code

}
```

The problem I am facing is when I try to deploy, I am getting the following exception.
If I remove `abstract` from `EmployeeDAOImpl` and remove `extends GenericDAO<Employee>` from `EmployeeDAO` then application gets deployed without errors. So it is not possible to have `abstract` class for `EmployeeDAOImpl` or I have need to implement all methods of `GenericDAO` in DAO implementation without `abstract`?

```
Error creating bean with 
name 'employeeService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; \
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Could not autowire field: test.dao.EmployeeDAO 
test.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDAO; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No matching bean of type [test.dao.EmployeeDAO] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for 
this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@javax.inject.Inject()}.
```

**Edit 1**

**GenericDAOImpl**

```
public class GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T> {    

    public void create(T entity) {
    }       
    public void update(T entity) {
    }
    public void delete(T entity) {
    }
```

**EmployeeDAOImpl**

```
public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Employee> implements EmployeeDAO {
```

Comment: You cannot create instance (bean) of abstract class, it is in java specification. Create `abstract GenericDAOImpl<T> implements GenericDAO<T>` with implementation and inherit `EmployeeDAOImpl` from `GenericDAOImpl<Employee>`.

Comment: @user1516873 method like `findEmployee` is specific to `Employee` `Entity` and `EmployeeDAO`. is it a good idea to include that in `GenericDAOImpl` ?

Comment: I usually add to CRUD methods in generic dao something like findById, findAll, removeById. Everything beyond goes in domain object specific iface/impl. In your case `findEmployee` definetly should be in `EmployeeDAO`, not in `GenericDAO`.

Comment: @user1516873 so you mean to say that create,update and delete should be specific to Entity or domain?

Comment: CRUD operation are common and can be moved in generic class. So it is domain specific. Of cource you can override it in Entity specific dao, if needed.

Comment: @user1516873 I have created `GenericDAOImpl<T>` and in `EmployeeDAOImpl` I extend `GenericDAOImpl` and implements `EmployeeDAO` like the following `public class EmployeeDAOImpl extends GenericDAOImpl<Employee> implements EmployeeDAO {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java (and consequently Spring) cannot create instances of abstract classes: every method must have an implementation before Java will let you create an instance, otherwise you would get a runtime error when you tried to call the method. You need to remove "abstract" from EmployeeDAOImpl and implement the methods inherited from GenericDAO.

Comment: Stephen So is it a best practice to implement all methods of GenericDAO in EmployeeDAOImpl as create update and delete are common methods for all DAO classes and are of generic type.

Comment: There are various patterns for this, none of them are particularly nice solutions. In Java 8 you will be able to define default implementations for interfaces (similar to mixins) which will make this a lot easier. In the mean time you could create an abstract GenericDOAImpl that provides default implementations of CRUD, then have EntityDAOImpl extend GenericDOAImpl

Comment: Stephen I have modified my `EmployeeDAOImpl` and `GenericDOAImpl`  as mentioned in my question as Edit 1, kindly have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to declare a class implementation as abstract? Conceptually it's a contradiction. Obviously Spring cannot instantiate it and fails.

Answer (score 1):

Confirm if your EmployeeDAOImpl or other annotated class packages are mentioned in spring context xml in following tag. Unless this is done, annotations won't get read and will not be initialized.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.app.service" />
```

Comment: Yes it does a package scan in applicationContext.xml